# Deploy jar to a gemfire locator programmatically

Tags: jar, gemfire

Is there an way to deploy a jar to a remote cache server programmatically? I'd rather avoid having a local GemFire installation just to use `gfsh` for deployment..

Answer (score 1):

You can talk to the locator using the REST protocol if you want to avoid installing `gfsh` locally.

`gfsh` can be configured to talk REST to the locator. For this, you have to start the locator using the gemfire property `http-service-port: 8080` and then while connecting to the locator from `gfsh` use:

```
gfsh>connect --use-http
```

Now, rather than gfsh, you can curl your jar to the locator (which will then send it to all the servers).

```
curl --fail -s -Fresources=@/path/to/your.jar http://locatorhost:port/gemfire/v1/deployed
```

This comes with the usual note about being brittle since the endpoint may change.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the GemFire/Geode source code on github:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode

The classes involved in deploying jars for GFSH are:

- com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.commands.DeployCommands
- com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.functions.DeployFunction
- com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.functions.UndeployFunction
- com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.functions.ListDeployedFunction

The above functions use the following which do the actual work:

- com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.JarDeployer
- com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.JarClassLoader

So, you could theoretically write some code using JarDeployer and JarClassLoader. They are internal classes so they're a) not official user/developer APIs, and b) might change or be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the startup scripts, e.g., $GEMFIRE_HOME/bin/'gemfire' in your remote installation. It looks like you can copy the jars to a location(s) accessible to each cache server and set the CLASSPATH environment variable to include the jars. Having said that, it's likely easier and more reliable to just use gfsh, especially if you have more than one cache server.